# how to authenticate token of authenticated user by calling API provided by server

Tags: spring, security, single-sign-on

```
@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authenti) throws AuthenticationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //String token=authenti.implies("userdetails");
    //UserDetails u=(UserDetails) authenti.getDetails();
    //String accessToken=authenti.

    //String aceToken=HttpServletRequest.this.getAttribute("accessToken");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a using of custom AuthenticationProvider in your case is not the best idea: in its overrided methods you are already working with authentication, so the Token should be handled before authentication.

Filter is better place for that:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = null;
            String token = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            if (StringUtils.hasText(token) && token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwt = token.substring(7, token.length());
            }
            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                Long personId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt); //it may be another identifier - unique name, email, etc.
                UserDetails userDetails = customDetailsService.loadUserById(personId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (JwtException exception) { //collecting custom exception from token provider class
        //create and send error
        //response.sendError or with response.getOutputStream()
        }
    }
}
```

After that information from token will be in the Authentication instance and you can handle it in any place.

Comment: Which details do you need? If you use a standard token - JWT - JSON Web Token, it has some specification and contains not a lot information - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token. But for identification of the User you need just its identifier. By it you can get any information in the Filter or AuthenticationProvider (or anywhere else), then you need create the Principle - an instance of UserDetails and point it for Authentication object.

Comment: Then in any place of your application, for example, in the Controller, you can get the Authentication object and with authentication.getPrincipal() or authentication.getDetails() you can get all information about the User.

Comment: If you identify the User, you should know (get from db) his roles. And UserDetails object MUST know them, it has `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()` method. So simply I don't see problems in your case.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what do you want to get (the subject of question).

Comment: Token should not contain such information like roles - it's unsafe. But if you have such information in the Token, you need to search a ready library for work with JWT or find implementation of the JwtProvider.

Comment: A lot of information you can find on the original JWT resource - https://jwt.io/, including ready libraries. I advice jsonwebtoken